# How I can set public static ip address in network printer?

Tags: printer

I'm looking for printer which supports (public static ip address).

So I can send print command from Windows VPS.

Thankx in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Although this site is not about giving ideas for specific printers, I can answer this without doing just that.

Every network printer that has a LAN or WIFI connection will work. By default they are set to DHCP and will get an IP address from the DHCP, but once you enter their configuration panel (website, by accessing the ip in your browser), you will be able to set a static IP. Thus far I haven't seen a network printer that did not support this, and I've seen many.